POSIX shell script with a config file, loading it correctly
I am a bit struggling with my Linux POSIX shell script (testing with ShellCheck and on Dash shell).
Until now, I never needed any config file for my scripts. I used variables in the top of my scripts. However, it appears, users dislike opening script and making edits, instead they would like a separate file for tweaks.
Say we have a script named myScript and in the same directory we have configuration file named myScript.conf. I might have gotten it working, I'd like to verify with your help that my loading procedure is correct and will work under various scenarios.
Minimal snippets:
myScript.conf:
var1=stringA
var2=stringB

myScript:
#!/bin/sh

error()
{
    printf >&2 '%s\n' "$@"
    exit 1
}

script_dir=$( dirname "$0" )
config_file="$script_dir"/myScript.conf

if [ ! -f "$config_file" ]; then
    error "The configuration file does not exist or it is not a regular file."
fi

if [ ! -r "$config_file" ]; then
    error "The configuration file exists, but it is not readable by this script."
fi

. "$config_file"

#
# DO SOME GOOD STUFF BASED ON CONFIG VARIABLES
#


Suggest [ -s "$config_file" ] for a single check that the file exists and has a size greater than zero (e.g. is non-empty). Simple sourcing the config is the proper way to approach handling the split script/config file setup. It's used throughout Unix/Linux. The benefit is you eliminate the chance somebody screws up the script by limiting their edits to a file that is sourced. Of course, that doesn't eliminate wrong or out-of-range variables being provided in the config.


will it work if there is a space in path

Yes. Check your scripts with shellcheck.

do I really need to do dirname "$0"?

That depends where from do you want to load your config file. If you want to load it from the directory the same as the script is stored in, then yes. The other mnemonic is dir="$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$0")")" to also handle symlinking.
